# Why was my close flag disputed?

Tags: support, triage, disputed-flags

I marked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984063/upload-multiple-images-and-inserted-into-separate-field-in-database-using-php-an) as a duplicate of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636877/how-can-i-store-and-retrieve-images-from-a-mysql-database-using-php). That is a clearly a duplicate, the OP didn't even try to use search. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636877/how-can-i-store-and-retrieve-images-from-a-mysql-database-using-php) beside the answer there are a lot of useful links and info, so I think it fully answers the OP's question. And I can't re-raise the flag.

So if I'm not right, please explain me where I was wrong, so I'll take it for the future.

Comment: DIsputed doesn't necessarily  mean you're wrong.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag

Comment: @naltipar yes, I know it. I have couple disputed flag with which I'm ok, but the problem is that I can't re-raise the flag. Will this question come up in someone's review queue? Anyway, I appreciate your reply.

Comment: Disputed flags can be regarded as positive feedback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question was handled and completed in the [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/10376651) queue.

As you can see

[image: review outcome, 3 looks good, 1 unsalvageable]

you were the only user to take the time and effort to find a duplicate. Instead of honoring you with all kind compliments for doing that the 3 other users arriving on that review felt the question was good enough (and I admit I have seen worse in [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)) and choose *Looks OK*. With that the review was complete and you 'lost' the vote, hence the dispute flag. I've gone ahead and casted a duplicate vote to get the question into the Close Vote Queue.

Do know that disputed flags are not held against you (at least not automatically) so there is not much harm done in that sense.

Don't stop finding duplicates and flagging them, please. Duplicates are important as they link similar questions with different wording to the same quality answers. Finding good duplicate targets is hard and not everyone is aware of them or wants to invest the time to find them and close vote/flag them.

Finding and flagging duplicates is the correct thing to do. Just be prepared to get some disputed flags, though.

One final note: Try to keep your calm when commenting. For the casual reader your comments can be seen as on the edge of passive/aggressive. Try to keep it factual.